# Third Level CascadingDropDown Not Passing SelectedValue to Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, cascadingdropdown

I am attempting to use the ASP.NET **CascadingDropDown** control to render values and the answers the user selected. The first two dropdown's always show the answer the user selected the last time they visited the page. I am also able to select new values and save them and they are stored correctly in the database. The problem is the next time I come to this page to edit the drop down values the first two correctly show the answer the user selected but the third one does not).

How do I get this third drop down to show correctly? When debugging it looks like the selected value is not passed to the GetTaxo method on the server.

I am using a repeater to output a custom control that contains the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="cboResponse" DataTextField="lov_label" 
   DataValueField="lov_cd" EnableViewState="True" runat="server" />

<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CDDL" runat="server" Category="-"
   EnableViewState="True" ServiceMethod="GetTaxo"
   ServicePath="/ajax/SaT.asmx" 
   TargetControlID="cboResponse" PromptValue="-1" PromptText="(Select One)" 
   LoadingText ="Loading..." />
```

In the code-behind I set the category and the **CascadingDropDown**'s SelectedValue :

```
CDDL.Category = questionId
CDDL.SelectedValue = cboResponse.SelectedValue
```

When the page is rendered, I see no problem as SelectedValue is set. The dropdown with Category=5149 but it doesn't appear to pass it's SelectedValue to the server:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownBehavior, {"Category":"4548","ClientStateFieldID":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl03_ctl02_CDDL_ClientState","LoadingText":"Loading...","PromptText":"(Select One)","PromptValue":"-1","SelectedValue":"MyAnswer","ServiceMethod":"GetTaxo","ServicePath":"/ajax/SaT.asmx","id":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl03_ctl02_CDDL"}, null, null, $get("ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl03_ctl02_cboResponse"));
});

document.getElementById('ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl03_ctl02_valSelectionRequired').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl03_ctl02_valSelectionRequired'));
}
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownBehavior, {"Category":"4025","ClientStateFieldID":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl04_ctl02_CDDL_ClientState","LoadingText":"Loading...","ParentControlID":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl03_ctl02_cboResponse","PromptText":"(Select One)","PromptValue":"-1","SelectedValue":"MyAnswer2","ServiceMethod":"GetTaxo","ServicePath":"/ajax/SaT.asmx","id":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl04_ctl02_CDDL"}, null, null, $get("ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl04_ctl02_cboResponse"));
});

document.getElementById('ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl04_ctl02_valSelectionRequired').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl04_ctl02_valSelectionRequired'));
}
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownBehavior, {"Category":"5149","ClientStateFieldID":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl05_ctl02_CDDL_ClientState","LoadingText":"Loading...","ParentControlID":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl04_ctl02_cboResponse","PromptText":"(Select One)","PromptValue":"-1","SelectedValue":"MyAnswer3","ServiceMethod":"GetTaxo","ServicePath":"/ajax/SaT.asmx","id":"ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl05_ctl02_CDDL"}, null, null, $get("ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl05_ctl02_cboResponse"));
});

document.getElementById('ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl05_ctl02_valSelectionRequired').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ucInvEdit_ucQuestionRepeater_rptQuestions_ctl05_ctl02_valSelectionRequired'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using the ContextKey attribute to pass the answer to the server. It's duplicating the knownCategoryValue's purpose but this control is flakey and I needed to get it done so I ended up using contextKey to get the correct answer selected.